# Configuring my hosting with GCS so my HTML website can send emails using a PHP script

Tags: php, html, forms, google-cloud-platform, hosting

I have an HTML form for people to fill out on my HTML website, and I would like that when they click on the send email button, it will send the email.

I'm using a PHP script to take care of building and sending the email with the info submitted on the HTML form.

My question is actually regarding the hosting configuration. What do I need to configure when setting up my server on google cloud services, either a virtual machine or a bucket for this purpose (I know there are easier way for doing so with another provider).

Below the PHP script in case someone wants to use it.

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_lastname = $_POST['cf_lastname'];
$field_subject = $_POST['cf_subject'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];


$mail_to = 'cjddws@gmail.com';
$subject = .$cf_subject;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message = .$field_lastname."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to cjddws@gmail.com');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/mail/sending-receiving-with-mail-api?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation [Hosting a static website](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website): "This tutorial describes **how to configure a Cloud Storage bucket to host a static website** for a domain you own. Static web pages can contain client-side technologies such as HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. **They cannot contain dynamic content such as server-side scripts like PHP.**". Please provide more details if your use case is different.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation [Hosting a static website](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website):

> This tutorial describes how to configure a Cloud Storage bucket to
>   host a static website for a domain you own. Static web pages can
>   contain client-side technologies such as HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
>   **They cannot contain dynamic content such as server-side scripts like PHP**.

**To solve this issue** you can use other GCP products. For example, you can move your site to GCE VM instance. You can find step by step instructions in the example [Setting Up LAMP on Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-lamp):

> This page shows you how to get a LAMP stack running on a Google
>   Compute Engine virtual machine instance. Follow the steps in this
>   tutorial to configure LAMP on a Debian, Ubuntu, or CentOS instance.
>
> Alternatively, you can use the [Google Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher) to deploy a
>   LAMP stack automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, however, I ended it up using a javascript function to avoid using the PHP with all the hosting changes I had to do.